# cannot compile a simple hbase java program

Tags: java, api, classpath, hbase

The following program is compiled using this command:-

```
javac MyLittleHBaseClient.java -cp /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-client.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-common.jar:/etc/hbase/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-server.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-hadoop-compat-0.98.6-cdh5.3.0.jar:/usr/lib/hbase/hbase-client-0.98.6-cdh5.3.0.jar
```

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Get;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Table;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;

public class MyLittleHBaseClient {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    config.addResource("/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml");
    Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
    try {
      Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("myTable"));
      try {
        Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleRow"));
        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleFamily"), Bytes.toBytes("someQualifier"),
        Bytes.toBytes("Some Value"));
        table.put(p);

        Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleRow"));
        Result r = table.get(g);
        byte [] value = r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleFamily"),
          Bytes.toBytes("someQualifier"));

        String valueStr = Bytes.toString(value);
        System.out.println("GET: " + valueStr);

        Scan s = new Scan();
        s.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleFamily"), Bytes.toBytes("someQualifier"));
        ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(s);
        try {
           for (Result rr = scanner.next(); rr != null; rr = scanner.next()) {
             System.out.println("Found row: " + rr);
           }

           // The other approach is to use a foreach loop. Scanners are iterable!
           // for (Result rr : scanner) {
           //   System.out.println("Found row: " + rr);
           // }
         } finally {
           scanner.close();
         }
       } finally {
         if (table != null) table.close();
       }
     } finally {
       connection.close();
     }
  }
}
```

Which results in the following errors. I do not understand why I am getting the following error as the hbase-client jar is added to the classpath.

```
 MyLittleHBaseClient.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
  import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection;
                                       ^
    symbol:   class Connection
    location: package org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client
  MyLittleHBaseClient.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
  import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory;
                                       ^
    symbol:   class ConnectionFactory
    location: package org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client
  MyLittleHBaseClient.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
  import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Table;
                                       ^
    symbol:   class Table
    location: package org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client
  MyLittleHBaseClient.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
      Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
      ^
    symbol:   class Configuration
    location: class MyLittleHBaseClient
  MyLittleHBaseClient.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
      Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
      ^
    symbol:   class Connection
    location: class MyLittleHBaseClient
  MyLittleHBaseClient.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
      Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
                              ^
    symbol:   variable ConnectionFactory
    location: class MyLittleHBaseClient
  MyLittleHBaseClient.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
        Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("myTable"));
        ^
    symbol:   class Table
    location: class MyLittleHBaseClient
  7 errors
```

Comment: Did you make sure that the jars are actually where you expect them to be, and have the correct read permissions?

Comment: Yes and no. Either that jar are there or they symlink to the location of the jar. And they all have rwx permission.

Comment: http://www.hastebin.com/nuqoqasusi.rb   I have uploaded the result of compiling the program in verbose mode. Maybe that will help with solving the issue.

Comment: Hmm. You seem to be using the cloudera JDK. Can you try it with the Oracle JDK?

Comment: No luck even with Oracle JDK. Here is the log http://www.hastebin.com/riqagekopi.rb

Comment: I'd suggest trying to use elimination: First create a Java source that has only the imports but nothing that uses them. See if the problem repeats, and then remove each import and see if it goes away. Also check your symbolic links - they may point to files that do not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. This should cover all of the jars under hbase and hadoop

```
javac -cp $(hbase classpath):$(hadoop classpath) MyLittleHBaseClient.java
```